# how to show element in browed page in selenium testing?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I tried this to do selenium testing

```
 require 'watir'
 b = Watir::Browser.start 'http://www.gmail.com'
 t = b.text_field id: 'entry_1000000'
 t.exists?
 t.set 'your name'
 t.value
```

but not fetching any text in browed page(www.gmail.com).

Comment: is the text_field id is constant? I am not able to find it?

Comment: I don't find the matching node with the given id.

Answer (score 0):

```
 require 'watir'
 b = Watir::Browser.start 'http://www.gmail.com'
 t = b.text_field id: 'entry_1000000'
 t.exists?
 t.set 'your name'
 t.value
```

put exact id of that text field . id or xpath or name etc

Answer (score 0):

First lets check if you have whats needed for that script to run, and start from there if not.

- Ruby installed
- Watir gem installed
- Browser installed (chrome or firefox)
- Geckodriver downloaded and in path (if firefox installed)
- Chromedriver downloaded and in path (if chrome installed)

After that, save the code below in file, lets name it *gmail.rb*.

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome #or :firefox    
b.goto "www.gmail.com"
b.text_field(:id => 'identifierId').set "your_email@gmail.com"
b.span(:text => "Next").click
b.text_field(:name => "password").set "your_password"
b.span(:text => "Next").click
```

Open command prompt or terminal and run the following command from folder where *gmail.rb* is located

```
ruby gmail.rb
```

Browser should open, navigate to gmail, input email, password and submit it, but from there gmail security kicks in so this is not a good use case for automation, at least not this way.

You can try the code above and see how it works, and if not, post errors here. But if you actually need to automate reading gmail, there is a really nice gem that helps you do that https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail